# How to return subclass type for a `set` method?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want have a class where the sets return `this` so I can do nested sets. But my issue is that the subclasses would also have some set's but if the user of the API calls first a set from the superclass the type changes and I can't call the subclass method.

```
class SuperA {
 public:
  SuperA* setValue(int x) {
    return this;
  }
}

class SubA : public SuperA {
 public:
  SubA* setOtherValue(int y) {
    return this;
  }
}

SubA* a = new SubA();
a->setValue(1)->setOtherValue(12); // Compile error
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Overload 'setValue' in 'SubA' (so it returns the correct type), or add 'setOtherValue' as a virtual function to 'SuperA'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search term for this is *covariant return type*.

You have to re-define `setValue` in the subclass: e.g.

```
class SubA : public SuperA
{
public:
    SubA *setValue(int x) { SuperA::setValue(x); return this; }
    // other methods...
};
```

In this example `setValue` is non-virtual, and `SubA::setValue` hides the base class version, it doesn't override.

If the function were virtual then this still works, with overriding happening, so long as the subclass version's return type is a pointer or reference to the superclass's version's return type.

Comment: That would only be true if you need `SubA::setValue()` to override `SuperA::setValue()` without using polymorphism.  But if `SuperA` and `SubA` need to set different things, there is no need to re-declare `setValue()` in `SubA`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If `setValue` is not redeclared then the code `a->setValue(1)->setOtherValue(12); ` fails, because the call to `setValue` returns `SuperA *`, and `SuperA` has no member function `setOtherValue` .

Answer (score 6):

I think this sounds like a job for...[Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)!

```
template <typename Child>
class SuperA
{
public:
    Child* setValue(int x)
    {
        //...
        return static_cast<Child*>(this);
    }
};

class SubA : public SuperA<SubA>
{
public:
    SubA* setOtherValue(int y)
    {
        //...
        return this;
    }
};
```

```
SubA* a = new SubA();
a->setValue(1)->setOtherValue(12); // Works!
```

Comment: @Matt McNabb Can you clarify your question? `SuperA` is already not abstract (in fact it has no virtual methods at all).

Comment: `SuperA` does not need to be abstract (or even virtual). By using templates in this manner, where `Child==SubA`, `SubA` is telling `SuperA::setValue()` to return a `SubA*` rather than a `SuperA*`.  It works perfectly fine (and is exactly how ATL avoids polymorphism limitations that prevent base class constructors/destructors from calling derived methods, which ATL does do).

Comment: @MarkB How would you write code to declare an object of type `SuperA` (perhaps in a context where `SubA` is not visible), and call the `setValue` function on it, and store the resulting pointer?  (This is possible without specifying a template parameter, in the original version)

Comment: @Matt McNabb That didn't seem to be a requirement of the question, but if it were you would create a non-template class from which the template `SuperA` inherited, with its own `setValue` method.